# Filter a Kendo UI MVC Grid using checked items in a checkbox column

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo UI MVC Grid where I'd like to add a special checkbox column.
This column will not be bound to a model but will be used like a sort of filter.

The idea is that users can check some rows and then click a button (for instance the filter icon in the column header). When clicked, the grid should collapse to the selected rows. The way I see it, it is an extra filter, but not the usual way.

The way my users will work with it would be about as follows:

1. They select a row and play the attached sound file for that row.
2. If the row holds an interesting sound file, they may check the checkbox and move to a new row -> 1.
3. After the selection with checkboxes is made, they will click on the checkbox column filter icon.
4. The selection will then collapse to the rows that were selected.
5. After this, the collapsed grid may be exported to excel, pdf or whatever…

A multi select grid is not an option as well as a checkboxed column filter because the selection is not instant, but a process over time.

I cannot find how I would make #4 work. Any suggestions? I don't need a complete solution, ideas are welcome.

[image]

Comment: 2 suggestions:
1. maybe you can post your existing code? 2.Search Telerik site demos/documentation/forums

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to add boolean 'util' property to your model and bind it to a checkbox column. Once your checkbox column will be bound, your button can execute:

```
dataSource.filter({ field:"Field", operator: "eq", value: true });
```

As far I know - there is no build kendo way to manage filtering unbounded columns.